# flex local database lastInsertId = 0

Tags: database, actionscript-3, sqlite, air, last-insert-id

```
var insertReq:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); 
insertReq.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, dbErrorHandler);
insertReq.sqlConnection = conn; 
insertReq.text = "INSERT INTO table1 (inputTime) VALUES (DATETIME('now'))";
insertReq.execute();
insertReq.text = "SELECT last_insert_rowid() as ID";
insertReq.execute();
var lastInsertId:int = insertReq.getResult().data[0].id;
trace(lastInsertId);
```

I made a local database and i am trying to insert some data but
I get `lastInsertId` zero?! Where I mess up things!?

Comment: solved by replacing 

    var lastInsertId:int = insertReq.getResult().data[0].id;

with

    var lastInsertId:int = parseInt(insertReq.getResult().data[0].id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to make additional execution of query for retrieving last inserted row's id.There is a built-in [**.lastInsertRowID**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html#lastInsertRowID) property of [**SQLResult**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html) class for that purpose. Just use it like this:

```
var insertReq:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); 
insertReq.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, dbErrorHandler);
insertReq.sqlConnection = conn; 
insertReq.text = "INSERT INTO table1 (inputTime) VALUES (DATETIME('now'))";
insertReq.execute();
var lastInsertId:int = insertReq.getResult().lastInsertRowID;
trace(lastInsertId);
```